# Change the Color of a Switch - FormBuilderSwitch - flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to change the Color for the Switch if normal an if switched. In the Material.dart I find some stuff but cannot write it right. If you could do some examples that would be great. Thank you

```
FormBuilderSwitch(
                  name: "public",
                  title: Text("Wird noch ein Mitspieler gesucht?"),
                  initialValue: widget.event?.public ?? false,
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
                ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use bool to do that

Example:

```
bool switched = false; //Based on which state you want it to be on init
```

Widget to trigger switch function

```
FormBuilderSwitch(
                        onChanged: (bool) {
                          setState(() {
                            bool = !bool;
                            switched = bool;
                          });
                        },
                      )
```

and here's an example of color change based on bool

```
Container(
   color: switched? Colors.white : Colors.blue,
)
```

Update :

Here's the code

```
FormBuilderSwitch(
              name: "public",
              title: Text("Wird noch ein Mitspieler gesucht?"),
              initialValue: false,
              controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
              decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
              onChanged: (bool) {
                setState(() {
                  bool = !bool;
                  switched = bool;
                });
              },
            ),
            Container(
              height: 20, 
              width: 20, 
              color: switched ? Colors.black54 : Colors.blue,
            ),
```

The outputs

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3j35.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUBpy.png

Update:

```
FormBuilderSwitch(
                  name: "public",
                  title: Text("Wird noch ein Mitspieler gesucht?"),
                  initialValue: false,
                  controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
                  activeColor: Colors.red
                  decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
                  onChanged: (bool) {
                    setState(() {
                      bool = !bool;
                      switched = bool;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 20, 
                  width: 20, 
                  color: switched ? Colors.red : Colors.black,
                ),
```

Comment: Thank you. But I do not want a new switch instead the formbuilderswitch. How can I handle it with the switch in the code?

Comment: I updated it with formbuilderswitch @AndreasSüßbauer

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it didn't work for me. The color do not change.

Comment: Can you give more details on what do you want to change color? @AndreasSüßbauer

Comment: The Color of the Container turns from black to red (i took the color red cause blue is the standard color for the switch), but the switch stays blue as you can see. I want to color the switch red too for example.    https://imgur.com/01xY0fy

Comment: Updated @AndreasSüßbauer

Comment: That's finally it! Thank you very much!